# Android Image Slider with zoom

Tags: android, slider

I'm using [this image slider](https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidImageSlider) and i really like it. But i need zoom option too is it possible to add zoom option to this?

Answer (score 0):

no its not supported, but you can add this feature to that, images showing on imageview and you can add this feature, for example this below code is which you want to have and add to support

```
public class Zoom extends View {

    private Drawable image;
    ImageButton img,img1;
    private int zoomControler=20;

    public Zoom(Context context){
            super(context);

            image=context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.j);
            //image=context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon);

            setFocusable(true);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        //here u can control the width and height of the images........ this line is very important
        image.setBounds((getWidth()/2)-zoomControler, (getHeight()/2)-zoomControler, (getWidth()/2)+zoomControler, (getHeight()/2)+zoomControler);
        image.draw(canvas);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            if(keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_UP){
                    // zoom in
                    zoomControler+=10;
            }
            if(keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_DOWN){
                    // zoom out
                    zoomControler-=10;
            }
            if(zoomControler<10){
                    zoomControler=10;
            }
            invalidate();
            return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Mahdi hello i did not understand how to use this can you help me please?